# Reporting on quarterly basis instead yearly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, report, moodle

I am using `reporting` in `Moodle` 2.8. Some guy before me created the `report`, which shows the `summ` of all seminar days from `3 different plugins`, where the numbers are put just in a fields (and **not** complexly calculated). So I get the following table:

```
  Username  | Seminar Days | Year
    --------+--------------+----------
    John    | 3            | 2013
    Maria   | 5            | 2013
    Paul    | 7            | 2012
```

The day are calculated by getting the days field from each seminar (and each from the 3 plugins), first with the following join we get the year:

```
                                              'dateyear',
                                              'LEFT',
                                              '(SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datefrom) AS year FROM {attendance} UNION ' .
                                                '(SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestart)) AS year FROM {seminar_paricipants}) UNION ' .
                                                '(SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datefrom) AS year FROM {private_seminars}))',
                                              '1',
                                              REPORT_BUILDER_RELATION_ONE_TO_MANY
```

And the calculate the days with two more joins from the 3 plugins we have and display them in the column **seminar days** with `CASE WHEN...` to check if some ar empty.

Is it possible to build filter function, so we can filter in the `year` on `quarter`(i.e from 01.01 until 31.03, from 01.04 until 31.06 etc.) basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is Totara rather than Moodle. Its a distribution of Moodle.

There is a very useful developers guide for report builder available from your partner or from Totara.

Do you know who your Totara partner is?

https://www.totaralms.com/partners

If you don't know the partner then I would suggest registering on the Totara community forums and asking for their advice.

https://community.totaralms.com/login/index.php